# Delete HTML table row dynamically using javascript with row index with link

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, delete-row

I wanted to dynamically add/delete table rows in HTML. I know there are quite a lot of questions in this forum with similar query. My doubt is to make the delete action applicable for each of the rows. For this, I was using the table index.

```
//Link
var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
var element7 = document.createElement("a");
var text = document.createTextNode("Delete");
element7.appendChild(text);
element7.setAttribute("href","javascript:deleterow("+rowcount+")");
element7.name="reqlink[]";
cell7.appendChild(element7);
```

Here rowcount is the index of the currently added row. So, while adding the row, I define the delete action as well. So, there will be a delete link for each of the row. However, the problem is the index varies dynamically. So, this solution will not really work.

Please can you help? I dont want to use the check box as defined by one of the solution.

The delete row function is scripted as follows:

```
function deleterow(index){
    alert('working' + index);
    table.deleteRow(index);
}
```

**######### Tried this ###########**

```
//Link
var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
var element7 = document.createElement("a");
var text = document.createTextNode("Delete");
element7.appendChild(text);
element7.setAttribute("href","javascript:deleterow(this); return false");
element7.name="reqlink[]";
cell7.appendChild(element7);
```

The "this" points to window and not the table row..

Comment: Give each of your table rows a unique Id and use that id to delete the row instead. Otherwise you could pass the parent row into the function instead of a specific number.

Comment: example, please.. Am inserting a row with this code:

var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

Comment: May I suggest you start upvoting some of the answers you are getting? :)

Answer (score 5):

Solution is to pass the current row element to the deleteRow function and remove it using its parent element(you can not remove it directly), so function will look like this:

```
 var deleteRow = function (link) {
     var row = link.parentNode.parentNode;
     var table = row.parentNode; 
     table.removeChild(row); 
 }
```

HTML for delete link is following

```
<a onclick="javascript:deleteRow(this); return false;">
```

Use following line to create element dynamically(also be careful with uppercase and lowercase characters):

```
element7.setAttribute("onclick","deleteRow(this); return false");
```

So, using ID's for deleting rows is unnecessary. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, "this" is not getting passed. Its window.. Now the row definition..

Comment: My mistake, do not thought about tables at all. This code works.

     var deleteRow = function (link) { 
      var row = link.parentNode.parentNode;

      var table = row.parentNode;
      table.removeChild(row);
     }

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting it. Please can you edit the answer? I am adding the table dynamically through javascript..

Comment: Edited the comment. Use onclick property instead on href. It may help.

Answer (score 1):

dont use index of the row. it is wrong on so many levels. imagine u deleted 1st 3 cells and your index has changed. if you want to delete the 4th row it will actually delete 7th row instead of 4th row in your actual table.

add a "data-id" field in your  which has a unique id for every row.
use this to delete the row.

BETTER SOLUTION:
this is in jQuery so find the js prototype equivalent.

```
$(this).closest("tr").html("")
```

and $(this) is your button which is clicked. so do the js equivalent of the above for 'click' event of the button.

Comment: What does closest mean?

Comment: in jQuery closest gives you the first element that is in the hierarchy of the DOM which has the element to which you call closest.      http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

```
    according to Aditya Shedge use closest itself. u can see closet definition here: http://api.jquery.com/closest/


here is an example:

<table id="foo" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>check</td>
                <td><input type="text></td>
                    <td><input type="text></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="addButton" value="add"/></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="deleteButton" value="delete"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>


<script>
$(function(){
    $(".addButton").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").clone(true).appendTo("#foo");
    });

    $(".deleteButton").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
});
</script>
```